# MultiRing buffer plugin to Python script in QGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-modeler, buffer

Is there a way to get the MultiRing buffer plugin into a Python script?

I want to use it in the QGIS Modeler, but I cannot use plugins in there, or to get multiple buffers with varied (not equal) steps into the Modeler.

Comment: The plugin is written in python, you can see the source code here: https://github.com/HeikkiVesanto/MultiRingBuffer

Comment: Yes i know and i copied already the source code, but my problem is that i dont know how and where i have to implement it. Can u help with that?